# What is this salt-water worm?

Tags: species-identification

We found this near Fort Pheonix in Buzzards Bay in Massachusetts. It gets long when its swimming (About 8 inches) and contracts when disturbed (2 inches).

Its head is shaped a bit like a diamond (like a cobra?). Its body looks fairly translucent and is ribbon-shaped.

[image: Still image of swimming]

Here's a short video: https://vimeo.com/240322590

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possibly a milky ribbon worm (Cerebratulus lacteus).

[image]

source:  intertidal-novascotia.blogspot.com

They can be found anywhere and everywhere along the Atlantic coastline in healthy abundance - http://intertidal-novascotia.blogspot.com/2012/05/cerebratulus-lacteus-milky-ribbon-worm.html